# How to dynamically grab a value using jquery for each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So i've been stuck trying to figure this out. I'm pretty sure I'm lacking a key piece of information. I'm grabbing some values from a JSON response. One contains a list of names. Another contains a list of URLs that correspond to the list of Names.

For instance:

```
{"names":"john,casey,davey",
    "nameUrls":[{
    "johnURL":"http://url.com",
    "caseyURL":"http://url.com",
    "daveyURL":"http://url.com"]}

    names = (data.names).split(',');

$.each(data.nameUrls, function(key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            $("#left").append(val[names[i] + "URL"]);
    }
    })
```

Now the first one comes through just fine. But the rest come in undefined. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: Adding more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing some syntax errors, here's the code which I tested in console and it's working.

```
  var data = {
        "names": "john,casey,davey",
        "nameUrls": {
            "johnURL": "http://url.com",
            "caseyURL": "http://url.com",
            "daveyURL": "http://url.com"
        }
    };
    names = (data.names).split(',');
    $.each(data.nameUrls, function (key, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            $("#left").append(val[names[i] + "URL"]);
        }
    });
```

In above lines, I just fixed the syntax errors, however I believe this might not let you achieve what you want. Try the below code and let me know.

```
var data = {
    "names": "john,casey,davey",
    "nameUrls": {
        "johnURL": "http://url1.com",
        "caseyURL": "http://url2.com",
        "daveyURL": "http://url3.com"
    }
};
names = (data.names).split(',');
$.each(data.nameUrls, function (key, val) {
    $("#left").append(val);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be working. I continue to get an undefined in the console. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that later, then I added the second half/part of the answer. Did you tried it? or both failed?

Comment: Great news :) glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you should restructure your data so that there is an easier association amongst it.

Would something like this work for you?

```
data = [
  {"name": "john", "url":  "http://url.com"},
  {"name": "casey", "url":  "http://url.com"},
  {"name": "davey", "url":  "http://url.com"}
];

$.each(data, function(index, person) {
  $('#left').append(person.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "names": "john,casey,davey",
    "nameUrls": {
        "johnURL": "http://url.com",
        "caseyURL": "http://url.com",
        "daveyURL": "http://url.com"
    }
};

$.each(data.names.split(','), function (i, v) {
    $("#left").append( v + " ==> " + data.nameUrls[v + 'URL'] );
});
```